# Extract value from dictionary in dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with a column with dictionaries.
I need to extract a value from the dictionary.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(x.edges(data=True), columns=['emp1','emp2','weight'])

       emp1     emp2         weight
0      Joan      Lee  {'weight': 3}
1      Joan     Andy  {'weight': 1}
2   Vincent    Frida  {'weight': 2}
```

I try to get just the value from the weight column

```
df['newweight'] = df.weight.apply(lambda x: x.get('value'))

       emp1     emp2         weight newweight
0      Joan      Lee  {'weight': 3}      None
1      Joan     Andy  {'weight': 1}      None
2   Vincent    Frida  {'weight': 2}      None
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `.str[]`

```
df.weight.str['weight']
```

Comment: Interesting. But strangely slower that just `df['newweight'] = [x['weight'] for x in df.weight]` (which is also faster than the apply method, btw).

Comment: You certainly meant `df.weight.str['weight']` btw. I edit accordingly (there is no `.str` to `df`)

Answer (score 2):

figured it out.

```
df['newweight'] = df.weight.apply(lambda x: x['weight'])
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: my earlier attempted line of code could have been simply fixed by (lambda x: x.get('weight')

Answer (score 1):

`x.get('value')` would look for the key called `'value'`, but your dictionary has only one key called `'weight'`.

[`dict.get` is specifically designed to return `None` when you attempt to `get` the value of a nonexistent key](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get), which is exactly what's happening here.